# Cypher: Extract unique values from collection

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have

```
MATCH (x)-[rels*]->(y)
RETURN extract( r in rels | r.property) as collected
```

where `collected` is a collection of properties of all relationships along the path, such as `[null, 4, null, 4]` or `[1, 3, 3, 1]`.

How can I further extract from `collected` only its unique values?
For example, `[null, 4, null, 4]` would change into `[null, 4]`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try this instead:

```
MATCH (x)-[rels*]->(y)
UNWIND rels AS rel
RETURN COLLECT( distinct rel.property) AS collected
```

Comment: Nulls will be skipped with collect distinct (afaik)

Comment: Interestingly, `... RETURN x.name, y.name, COLLECT( distinct rel.property) AS collected` does return (a table with) empty cells in place of (single) `null`s

Comment: add CASE statement:
COLLECT( distinct 
CASE rel.property
WHEN null THEN "null"
ELSE rel.property
END)