# In neo4j, extract unique elements from lists

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a database where nodes and relationships are created as such:

```
create ({foo: 1})-[:r]->({foo: 1}), ({foo: 1})-[:r]->({foo: 2}), ({foo: 1})-[:r]->({foo: 2})
```

For each path, I can generate lists of properties in this manner:

```
MATCH path = (start)-[*]->(end)
WHERE NOT ()-->(start) and NOT (end)-->()
RETURN [node in nodes(path) | node.foo] as foos
```

which returns

```
foos
------
[1, 1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
```

But I want only distinct properties in each list.

Inspired by [Cypher: Extract unique values from collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26634802/cypher-extract-unique-values-from-collection) I tried

```
MATCH path = (start)-[*]->(end)
WHERE NOT ()-->(start) and NOT (end)-->()
WITH [node in nodes(path) | node.foo] as foos
UNWIND foos as x
RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT x) as foos_unique
```

But this gives me unique properties across all nodes:

```
foos_unique
----
[1, 2]
```

How can I extract distinct elements from each list, so that the result will be

```
foos_unique
------
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UPDATED]

The [REDUCE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/functions/list/#functions-reduce) function will help:

```
MATCH path = (start)-[*]->(end)
WHERE NOT ()-->(start) and NOT (end)-->()
RETURN REDUCE(s = [], n in NODES(path) |
  CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS(n.foo) OR n.foo IN s THEN s ELSE s + n.foo END) as foos
```

Comment: This is almost perfect, only null values are not handled well. If I change the last line to `CASE WHEN n.foo IN s OR (n.foo IS NULL AND TRUE in [x IN s | x IS NULL]) THEN s ELSE s + [n.foo] END) as foos` then it works perfectly. @cybersam, if you agree with me and update your answer, I will accept this answer. Perhaps you even know a better way of checking lists for null values, this is the best I was able to do.

Answer (score 0):

This would do the job. Instead of collecting unique elements we can compare the `foo`s of `start` and `end` like this:

```
MATCH (start)-[*]->(end)
WHERE NOT ()-->(start) and NOT (end)-->()
WITH start.foo as foos, end.foo as fooe 
RETURN case when foos = fooe then [foos] else [foos, fooe] end as foos_unique
```

The output is:

```
foos_unique

[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
```

Comment: It works for this particular input, but if I add the path `create ({foo: 1})-[:r]->({foo: 2})-[:r]->({foo: 3})`, the result of your query will be `[1,3]`. But the desired result is `[1,2,3]`